# interactive-haskell-mode: Format specifier doesn't match argument type

Tags: haskell-mode

Pressing `C-c C-l` (for a simple "Hello, world!" script) in `interactive-haskell-mode` gives me the error message

```
Format specifier doesn't match argument type
```

whereas I would have expected the file being executed in a new buffer (resulting in the output `Hello, world!").

The script consists fo the single line

```
main = putStrLn "Hello, world!"
```

I cannot make much sense of the error message. Does anyone has an idea which additional diagnostics I could run in order to pin down the problem?

There is a loosely related (open) issue on *GitHub* https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/1429 resulting in the same error message for *Haskell* snippets in `org-mode`.

I'm using *Emacs 25.2.2* from the official package on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.0.4 and also the `haskell-mode` package from the official repositories.

Comment: Can you show the code you use? You have an error message from using a script, apparently, but you don't show the code of that script.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I added the content of the script. I hadn't put it in the first place because I think the message is an error message from *Emacs* (and not from the *Haskell* interpreter).

Comment: `C-c C-l` is bound to `haskell-process-load-file`. The `Format specifier doesn't match argument type` is an *elisp* error message as far as I see. The *Haskell* script runs without problems in the *Haskell* interpreter (and can also be compiled without problems.

Comment: There is a related issue on GitHub <https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/1480> describing how to set up `interactive-haskell-mode`.